# How to determine process is complete or not in Process Sales Order

Tags: cloud, erp, acumatica

I create extension for Invoice in Distribution Module (SO303000). I need to create payment automatically when release it base on current Invoice. I have been successful with single invoice by using this code below

```
    public PXAction<ARInvoice> release;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Release", Visible = false)]
    [PXButton()]
    public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        Base.Release(adapter);
        PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(Base.UID);
        ARPaymentEntry arPaymentEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARPaymentEntry>();
        ARPayment payment = arPaymentEntry.Document.Insert();
        payment.CustomerID = Base.Document.Current.CustomerID;
        payment.CustomerLocationID = Base.Document.Current.CustomerLocationID;
        payment.PaymentMethodID = "TM";
        Branch branch = PXSelect<Branch>.Select(new PXGraph());
        CashAccount ca =
            PXSelect<CashAccount, Where<CashAccount.branchID, Equal<Required<CashAccount.branchID>>>>
                .Select
                (new PXGraph(),
                    branch.BranchID).FirstTableItems.FirstOrDefault();
        if (ca != null)
        {
            payment.CashAccountID = ca.CashAccountID;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new PXException("Cannot find the Cash Account.");
        }
        payment.ExtRefNbr = "Auto";
        payment.Hold = false;
        payment.CuryOrigDocAmt = Base.Document.Current.CuryLineTotal;
        arPaymentEntry.Document.Current = payment;
        arPaymentEntry.Document.Cache.Update(arPaymentEntry.Document.Current);

        ARAdjust arAdjust = new ARAdjust();
        arAdjust.AdjdRefNbr = Base.Document.Current.RefNbr;
        arAdjust.AdjgRefNbr = arPaymentEntry.Document.Current.RefNbr;
        arAdjust.AdjgDocType = arPaymentEntry.Document.Current.DocType;
        arAdjust.AdjdDocType = Base.Document.Current.DocType;
        arAdjust.CustomerID = Base.Document.Current.CustomerID;
        arAdjust.AdjdBranchID = branch.BranchID;
        arAdjust.AdjgBranchID = branch.BranchID;
        arAdjust.AdjdDocDate = Base.Document.Current.DocDate;
        arAdjust.AdjdFinPeriodID = Base.Document.Current.FinPeriodID;
        arAdjust.Released = false;
        arAdjust.Voided = false;
        arPaymentEntry.Adjustments.Insert(arAdjust);
        ARAdjust arAdjusted = (ARAdjust) arPaymentEntry.Adjustments.Update(arAdjust);
        arPaymentEntry.Adjustments.Current = arAdjusted;
        var arAdapter =
            new PXAdapter(new DummyView(arPaymentEntry, arPaymentEntry.Document.View.BqlSelect,
                new List<object> {arPaymentEntry.Document.Current}))
            {

            };
        arPaymentEntry.Save.Press();

        arPaymentEntry.Release(arAdapter);
    }
```

. But in process invoice and payment screen (SO505000). I have to change my code into that because when process in page SO505000, they will pass list into adapter so I need to using loop. I want to use PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion to determine which invoice is released or not.

```
    public PXAction<ARInvoice> release;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Release", Visible = false)]
    [PXButton()]
    public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        var list = Base.Release(adapter);
        var invList = adapter.Get<ARInvoice>();
        foreach (var inv in invList)
        {
            ARPaymentEntry arPaymentEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARPaymentEntry>();
            ARPayment payment = arPaymentEntry.Document.Insert();


            payment.CustomerID = inv.CustomerID;
            payment.CustomerLocationID = inv.CustomerLocationID;
            payment.PaymentMethodID = "TM";
            Branch branch = PXSelect<Branch>.Select(new PXGraph());
            CashAccount ca =
                PXSelect
                    <CashAccount, Where<CashAccount.branchID, Equal<Required<CashAccount.branchID>>>>
                    .Select
                    (new PXGraph(),
                        branch.BranchID).FirstTableItems.FirstOrDefault();
            if (ca != null)
            {
                payment.CashAccountID = ca.CashAccountID;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new PXException("Cannot find the Cash Account.");
            }
            payment.ExtRefNbr = "Auto";
            payment.Hold = false;
            payment.CuryOrigDocAmt = inv.CuryLineTotal;
            arPaymentEntry.Document.Current = payment;
                   arPaymentEntry.Document.Cache.Update(arPaymentEntry.Document.Current);

            //arPaymentEntry.Save.Press();
            ARAdjust arAdjust = new ARAdjust();
            arAdjust.AdjdRefNbr = inv.RefNbr;
            arAdjust.AdjgRefNbr = inv.RefNbr;
            arAdjust.AdjgDocType = inv.DocType;
            arAdjust.AdjdDocType = inv.DocType;
            arAdjust.CustomerID = inv.CustomerID;
            arAdjust.AdjdBranchID = branch.BranchID;
            arAdjust.AdjgBranchID = branch.BranchID;
            arAdjust.AdjdDocDate = inv.DocDate;
            arAdjust.AdjdFinPeriodID = inv.FinPeriodID;
            arAdjust.Released = false;
            arAdjust.Voided = false;
            arPaymentEntry.Adjustments.Insert(arAdjust);
            ARAdjust arAdjusted = (ARAdjust) arPaymentEntry.Adjustments.Update(arAdjust);
            arPaymentEntry.Adjustments.Current = arAdjusted;
            var arAdapter =
                new PXAdapter(new DummyView(arPaymentEntry, arPaymentEntry.Document.View.BqlSelect,
                    new List<object> {arPaymentEntry.Document.Current}))
                {

                };
            arPaymentEntry.Save.Press();

            arPaymentEntry.Release(arAdapter);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution by this code below. Thanks for all support.

```
     public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
       var refNbrList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       var invList = adapter.Get<ARInvoice>();
        foreach (var inv in invList)
        {
                PXDatabase.Execute("pp_DMS_SO_Invoice_InsertSettleDate",
               new PXSPInParameter("@CompanyID", PXContext.GetSlot<int?>("singleCompanyID")),
               new PXSPInParameter("@InvoiceType", inv.DocType),
               new PXSPInParameter("@InvoiceNBR", inv.RefNbr));
                ARInvoiceEntry invoiceEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARInvoiceEntry>();
                invoiceEntry.Document.Current = inv;
                invoiceEntry.Document.Cache.Update(invoiceEntry.Document.Current);
                var arInvoiceAdapter =
                               new PXAdapter(new DummyView(invoiceEntry, invoiceEntry.Document.View.BqlSelect,
                                   new List<object> { invoiceEntry.Document.Current }))
                               { };
                invoiceEntry.Release(arInvoiceAdapter);
                PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(invoiceEntry.UID);
                // create payment here
         }
     }
```

Comment: you can mark this question as answered by accepting the answer, which helps others to check for the answers and to save time for those who is trying to answer by reading the full question.

Answer (score 0):

Simon,
you can check Released flag right in foreach loop.

`foreach (var inv in invList)
    {
        if (inv.Released == true)
        {
            //your custom code here
        }
    }`

Comment: but I am not sure the process of release invoice is complete or not. the invoice must be released.

Comment: Simon, why not use WaitCompletion() again?

Comment: At the 1st times, I wanna to make sure that the invoice has been released. So I have to do that. Btw I have found solutions: